# Is it okay to remove unknown accounts from /etc/passwd?

Tags: linux, user-accounts

Accounts like lp, bin, daemon, ftp, etc. look like legacy accounts that I won't need on my servers but are installed by default.

Is there an easy way to detect which accounts are required?  I see things like "daemon" which I don't want to break all daemons, but I don't know how this account is used. The same for "sync", "operator", and many others.

I'm looking for some means other than just removing the account, rebooting, and seeing if anything looks broken.

Editing to add, DISA (DoD) requires it:  https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/red_hat_enterprise_linux_8/2021-12-03/finding/V-230379

Comment: How many accounts do you have. If not too many (less than 1.5 dozen) leave them, especially if you do not know what they are

Comment: @John, it's a long story, but basically the security compliance protocols (written by a different agency) require me to delete any which aren't used.  Those used must be justified.

Comment: Unless someone you can talk to can give you assurance about what to delete, then I would not delete them. Is the presence of these passwords causing a problem?  Probably not.

Comment: @John, that isn't the way cyber security works.  You can't just keep unknown, undocumented accounts around and hope for the best.  These seem to be standard accounts across Unix/Linux installs. Surely someone knows what they are.

Comment: You listed accounts that looked normal to me. I do not delete such Windows passwords. I am not just hoping for the best and my PC is VERY secure.

Comment: I would push back against the compliance group. DOD/DOE/foo should follow NIST standards for account compliance. The normal accounts and groups in most Linux distributions are allowed, only user accounts outside the normal range should be inspected. Don't delete default accounts in `/etc/passwd` unless the compliance group can confirm that the deletion is required and will not impact the system. I am in an HHS division and have to work with NIST standards on a regular basis.

Comment: @doneal24 - [They do follow NIST standards. The author can’t just, push back if it’s a requirement](https://public.cyber.mil/stigs/). Their ISSM could put it in their security documentation but there has be justification to do so. I would agree one should not just remove lines from the passwd file but properly remove the user and their home directory  I speak from experience in securing Linux operating system that satisfy the security requirements of the DoD.

Comment: @davidhaskins - “Is there an easy way to detect which accounts are required?” - Identify the accounts you need based on the systems configuration and disable any account from being able to log into the system.  What accounts can be enabled will depend on your systems configuration and the ISSO

Comment: @Ramhound, yes, this is DoD.  I edited the post to add the STIG check.  You are right, I need the ISSM to sign off, and the ISSM won't sign off unless I can prove the accounts are necessary.

Comment: You could make a system image of your install first, ensure that you can restore it, then remove them and see if all still works. If not, then you can restore the image and check that they are needed or it breaks the install. Or leave them disabled.

Comment: @LPChip, that is what I want to avoid doing.  Mostly because I can't exhaustively test it.  I mean, it may boot up and look fine, but it's possible some dependency causes something like a mailer daemon or audit logging to fail.

Comment: @Ramhound We also have to follow NIST standards to be FISMA level 2 compliant. DOD STIGs may require removal of system accounts but the NIST SP series does not.

Comment: @Ramhound Now that the OP edited the question to include follow DOD, then yes he has no other option.